# Create multiple dataframes from files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder with a lot of files. I want to create a loop or function where I can read all the files and create corresponding data frames for each one of the files with the prefix format `'filename'+_df`.

I have this code that reads everything and creates a large data frame from all the files in the folder, but I'm not sure how to modify it to create multiple data frames and use the filename as a prefix:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'folder')

files = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i))]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    _df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df = df.append(_df)
```

If there's a better way to do this, that would be great as well.

Comment: you can store all the DataFrames into a list. Then concat all dataframes into one

Comment: I don't want to create a single data frame. I want to create a data frame per file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary of DataFrames in dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs = {f'{file}_df': pd.read_csv(file) for file in files}
```

Then for each DataFrame select by key, e.g. `file='myfile'`:

```
dfs['myfile_df']
```

Thank you @Abdul Niyas P M for idea:

```
from pathlib import Path
dfs = {f'{Path(file).stem}_df': pd.read_csv(file) for file in files}
```

Or:

```
import os
dfs = {f'{os.path.basename(file)}_df': pd.read_csv(file) for file in files}
```

Comment: In the OP the `files` seems like a list of abs paths. May be you can use `Pathlib` to get only the filename. `dfs = {f'{Path(file).stem}_df': pd.read_csv(file) for file in files}`